# How to retrieve the redirect URL in phonegap android application when using custom oauth2 provider

Tags: android, cordova

I am implementing oauth2 using phonegap android application and have a problem of retrieving the redirect URL.

Below is the Redirect URL which the server is redirecting to on successful authorization.

```
http://localhost/tutorsapp/assets/www/#state=123&access_token=b3edb8eec17c7f99048f7132836dd822f0078a702842928e197efe37eba6959215216e1b677ca96906d5dfcc0ae17d35b4b1&token_type=bearer&expires_in=10800
```

I am wondering how to retrieve the redirected URL in Javascript so that I can save the access_token.

I tried window.location.href. But that does not work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the access_token and other params are in the hash fragment of the URL.

Use window.location.hash and parse the access_token